# Using parameters to limit user access in SQL / Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I'm looking at finding a way of restricting access to certain parts of a report using a parameter but I've yet to find a way to do this.

What I want to do is have the report get the persons username and then restrict what options they have available to them in the other parameters of the report.

> For example, John is a manager of the Call Centre department so John
>   shouldn't see the options for the other departments in the business
>   and should only see the 'Call Centre' option in the Department
>   parameter.

Is this possible? If it isn't, is there an alternative using something similar?

Comment: What about creating a report for each department with only the data they are allowed to see?

Comment: That was my initial thought but there are many departments and administration of that (limiting to a set user(s) within the department) would not be manageable long term.

Comment: You should use ausillary table that maps every user to its department and then join your report result to this table

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need someway of determining who shoudl be able to see what. At it's simplest you could build a table to do this with Users and Departments.

Then create a dataset in your report that returns only values departments, something like

```
SELECT DepartmentID, DepartmentName FROM UserDepartments WHERE UserName = SYSTEM_USER
```

I've used `SYSTEM_USER` here but this will only work if you are executing the dataset with windows authentication.

Then in your Department parameter, just set the available values to the dataset you just created.